# Slower performance on iOS release than development

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I've built a React Native iOS app which is fairly basic; it's a few screens which the user can click through to from a 'Home' component, and each one consists of basic components comprising solely Text/View/Image components.

In simulator the app is responsive and there aren't any JS console warnings, however when I do a release to my iPad (Air 2), there's a noticable lag between the home screen and certain other screens. These are notably the screens which have more images on.

I'm wondering if it's because I'm using larger images (the app was designed for the iPad Pro 2) and scaling the images down for use where I want them. The worst offender is a page which has a masonry-style grid of images. There's still only about 30 in a ScrollView there though. Once the component has been shown once the app is much more responsive.

I've already taken steps to optimise my components in terms of using extending PureComponent or using stateless functions wherever possible, and console logging shows me that the touchables are responding immediately, so the delay is definitely at the render time of the component.

N.B. All images are local (loaded via `require('./path/to/file')`), nothing is being loaded over the network.

Here's an example of the code that populates an array of items for display inside the ScrollView:

```
  ...
  const items = mediaItems.map((item, index) => {
    // scale desired width (1044 for video, 520 for images) based on designed width and device aspect ratio.
    const imageWidth = item.video ? (1044/2732) * deviceWidth : (520/2732) * deviceWidth 
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight key={index} onPress={() => onOpen(item)}>
        <View style={[styles.gridImageView, { width: imageWidth }]}>
          <Image style={styles.gridImage} source={item.image} />
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  });
  ...
```

and the styles for the `gridImageView` and `gridImage` are as follows:

```
  ...
  gridImageView: {
    height: (460/2732) * width,
    margin: (2/2732) * width,
    position: 'relative'
  },
  gridImage: {
    resizeMode: 'cover', 
    width: null,
    height: null,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  ...
```

So my question is kind of multi-layered:

- What is the best practice with regards to ensuring the component appears quickly?

  - Should I not be setting a width/height on the image itself at all?
  - Should I be doing some kind of pre-loading of the images in the sizes I want before I let the user begin to navigate around the app?
  - Should I be using JPG instead of PNG images?
  - Is there another trick I'm missing?

Comment: Is this more of a navigation issue where it glitches setting up the view or are you having to wait too long to see the images?

Comment: No I'm sure it's being caused by the images in the view. If I take them out the component renders very quickly.

Comment: What I meant to say is is the time ok if load the component with placeholders and after the navigation allow it to load or is it just the time. Have you tried setting the representation properly to get the appropriate size image.

Comment: If you are setting your images with flex then you are always getting the full size image when a smaller version could be used. Will also lead to high memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

`Should I not be setting a width/height on the image itself at all`

- You have to set a width and height. If you don‘t do so, your image won‘t display

`Should I be doing some kind of pre-loading of the images in the sizes I want before I let the user begin to navigate around the app?`

- It is a good idea to downlod images beforehand. Huge images need a lot of performance. Probably your issues are gone, if you resize your images before displaying them. Therefore you could use [react native image resizer](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer)

`Should I be using JPG instead of PNG images?`

- You should use JPGs, because they provide a higher compression rate.

Comment: The docs says I only need to specify width and height if I’m using a url or data based image. As stated in the question I’m using local images. Also how do I preload local images? Surely they are already loaded?

Comment: If you are using local images, you really need to resize and compress your images. For example with react-native-image-resizer as stated above.

Comment: And local images are loaded from a local path url, that means you have to specify height and width.

Comment: I’m had no issue with not specifying the height and width, and I am using require, not a uri for the local images, so I’m still not convinced I have to specify the width and height, but I think using the image resizer on app launch is a good idea

Comment: ah i did'nt know that you are using require (i've overlooked). Of course, then you don't need it, but it does not hurt either. 
Yes i think the image resizer should fix your performance issues.